# Is it possible to track javascript url redirects?

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose I have 1 web page, in that page I embed JavaScript `window.location=http://some-site.com`. Is is possible to track the url redirects via PHP?

Comment: Not directly, but you can create one `php` from that you can `log` (may be in database) and then redirect using `header("Location: $url")`

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the referrer page's URL if one exists.

Comment: So, the javascript will become like this: `window.location=logger.php?url=http://some-site.com`, then in logger.php you get `$_GET['url']` and process accordingly.

Comment: @Log1c I have no access to the sites containing JS. I just need to track redirects.

Comment: Then its not possible from `PHP`. Because you are redirecting using javascript and have no control over javascript. What you can do is add [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/) code to header of your website. It will help you to track your website along with referring sites and much more.

Comment: @Log1c I found a solution, using cURL and extract URL from JS `window.location`

Comment: But you told, you don't have control over JS ?

Comment: @Log1c How well it will work?

Comment: I have no control on the page which has JS thats why I load the page using cURL PHP

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking. Please add more detail to your question. I'm confused.